# meaning of "look into ways of"

Tags: meaning

I learned this phrase in some lesson today

> you may want to **look into ways of** wearing natural makeup

A [post](https://qr.ae/pNyuqK) says it means

> to explore available methods or ponder how to do something.

with that meaning, does this one mean the same thing?

> you may want to **consider** wearing natural makeup

Comment: It does not mean quite the same thing. The first sentence is about finding out what kinds of natural makeup can be worn. Your version is about making a decision to wear natural makeup instead of processed makeup, rather than what kinds of natural makeup are available.

Comment: It's worth noting that that nuance of difference essentially arises because of ***ways of***. It's perfectly possible to say *You may want to look into wearing natural makeup* to make your first version carry a similar meaning to the second, or *You may want to consider **ways of** wearing natural makeup* to make the second version match the first more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sentences have different meanings.

The 1st sentence means you're finding out different **ways** of wearing natural makeup.

The 2nd sentence means you carefully think about wearing natural makeup for making a decision.

If you say, "You may want to consider **ways of** wearing natural makeup", then it means the same thing as the first sentence.